# Passing custom type parameters to stored procedures using PyODBC

Tags: python, t-sql, stored-procedures, prepared-statement, pyodbc

I have a type (of table) and a stored procedure:

```
CREATE TYPE [Scheduler].[CondType] AS TABLE (condition VARCHAR(32));

CREATE PROCEDURE [Scheduler].[SP_GetResult] 
    (@current_time AS NVARCHAR(5),                -- "%HH:%MM"
     @cond_table [Scheduler].[CondType] READONLY)
AS
    SELECT [name], [sched_time], [condition]
    FROM [Scheduler].[ScheduleTable]
    WHERE [condition] IN (SELECT condition FROM @cond_table)
      AND @current_time = [sched_time]
```

I want to call this stored procedure with the simple text parameter and the complex (list/table) parameter from Python:

```
# not important technical details
tokenstruct = ...
conn_str = "Driver=%s;Server=tcp:%s,1433;Database=%s;" % (cfg.driver, cfg.sql_server, cfg.sql_database)
conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str, attrs_before = { 1256:tokenstruct })
cursor = conn.cursor()

# input data
hour_and_minute = "08:00"
conditions = ["tuesday", "weekend"]
sql = "{ call Scheduler.SP_GetResult(@current_time=?, @cond_table=?) }"

# execute stored procedure
cursor.execute(sql, (hour_and_minute, conditions)) # but how to pass arguments properly here?
result_set = cursor.fetchall()
```

When I try to execute, the simple parameters is OK, but I get an exception like this for the table parameter:

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Column, parameter, or variable #2: Cannot find data type tuesday. (2715) (SQLParamData)')

or

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Column, parameter, or variable #2: Cannot find data type CondType. (2715) (SQLParamData)')

**Question:** how could I pass a table type parameter properly?

If I do this from SQL console, it works fine:

```
DECLARE @DL CondType;
INSERT @DL VALUES ('tuesday'), ('weekday');
EXEC [Scheduler].[SP_GetResult] @current_time = '08:00', @cond_table=@DL;
GO
```

I've tried to modify the passed parameter but I always get similar error:

```
conditions = ["tuesday", "weekend"]
conditions = [("tuesday", ), ("weekend", )]
conditions = ("tuesday", "weekend")
conditions = (("tuesday", ), ("weekend", ))
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: @marc_s Okay, thank you for the information! (I'm not a database expert)

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/595

Comment: @elaspog did you find a solution to this ? I am facing something similar.